# Own transferable returns no DataFlavor from outside application

Tags: java, clipboard, copy-paste

I have two applications:

**1.** My own `Image Explorer`. I want to operate with images via such options like `copy-paste`. I created own DataFlavor type for this. (Yeah, I really need that!) It is looks like

```
DataFlavor supportedFlavor = new DataFlavor(app.my.ImageWrapper.class, "ImageWrapper class");
```

And in my `Transferable` I use this `DataFlavor`:

```
            @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return supportedFlavor.equals(flavor);
        }

        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return new DataFlavor[]{supportedFlavor}; // Simpled for SSCCE, I don't create new flavor each time really
        }
```

**2.** FlavorListener from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5999515/2123487) answer. It should listen to `FlavorEvents` for detecting which data type is copied.

My problem is:

When I get the event from other application after copying the text, files, images, the `DataFlavor` is never null. But if I get the event after copying the my Object, it cannot detect any DataFlavor. WHY?

**PS:** Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: use clipboard to copy-paste java objects between different instances of same application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276182/java-use-clipboard-to-copy-paste-java-objects-between-different-instances-of-sa)

Comment: Your English isn't that bad, I have seen much worse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276182/java-use-clipboard-to-copy-paste-java-objects-between-different-instances-of-sa?rq=1) after looking to the related section. This really wasn't show in search field, strange, because it is the second time similar situation...